# Optimize Chunk in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

This subquery in my if() condition, stuck my code.
Anyone have idea for optimize this?

```
public function handle()
  {
    print " Searching person \n";

    DB::table('excercise_pessoa')->orderBy('id')->chunk(1000, function ($people) {
      foreach ($people as $person) {
        $excercise = Excercise::find($person->excercise_id);
        $course = $excercise->grade->course;
        $personReal = Pessoa::find($person->pessoa_id);

        if ($course->pessoas->where('id', '=', $person->pessoa_id)->count() == 0) {
          $course->pessoas()->attach($personReal);

          print " Associating course to people ID: $person->pessoa_id \n";
        }
      }
    });

    print " Finished migration! \n";
  }
```

Comment: Use relationship `manyToMany` for this optimisation

Comment: @A.ANoman how? I need verify if course was not duplicated for people

Answer (score 0):

I solve this way,

Remove if() condition and use:

`$course->pessoas()->syncWithoutDetaching($personReal);`